# ошибка при деплое java-проекта на heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

при пуше проекта на heroku получаю ошибку в мавене:

> $ git push heroku
> Enumerating objects: 718, done. Counting objects: 100% (718/718), done. Delta compression using up to 12
> threads Compressing objects: 100% (439/439), done. Writing objects:
> 100% (718/718), 1.16 MiB | 1005.00 KiB/s, done. Total 718 (delta 309),
> reused 415 (delta 165), pack-reused 0 remote: Compressing source
> files... done. remote: Building source: remote: remote: ----->
> Building on the Heroku-20 stack remote: -----> Determining which
> buildpack to use for this app remote: -----> Java app detected remote:
> -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done remote: -----> Executing Maven remote:        $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
> remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects... ... remote:
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE remote:        [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ remote:        [INFO] Total time:  10.547 s remote:        [INFO]
> Finished at: 2022-07-05T13:53:18Z remote:        [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project springboot_touristsite: Fatal error
> compiling:  invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1] remote:
> [ERROR] remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the
> errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. remote:        [ERROR] Re-run
> Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. remote:
> [ERROR] remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors
> and possible solutions, please read the following articles: remote:
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
> remote: remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven remote:
> We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in
> application code, remote:        please submit a ticket so we can
> help: https://help.heroku.com/ remote: remote:  !     Push rejected,
> failed to compile Java app. remote: remote:  !     Push failed remote:
> Verifying deploy... remote: remote: !       Push rejected to
> springboottouristsite. remote: To
> https://git.heroku.com/springboottouristsite.git  ! [remote rejected]
> master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
> some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/springboottouristsite.git'

меня смущала, что скачивается jdk 1.8:

> remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done

Поэтому в application.properties поставил java.runtime.version=11, в стуктуре проекта также поставил 11, и в ром файле, однако все равно скачивается 1.8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.zaitsava</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot_touristsite</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>springboot_touristsite</name>
<description>springboot_touristsite</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProperties>
                            <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                            <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                            <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                            <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                        </additionalProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Я так понимаю, что что-то не нравиться в pom-файле, особенно в плагине мавена, но что именно нужно изменить?

Comment: Heroku по умолчанию запускает с JDK8, вам нужно в корне проекта создать файл system.properties и в него записать java.runtime.version=11

Comment: спасибо, помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли ответом под вопросом
В корне проекта создал файл system.properties с записью java.runtime.version=11

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).